# Output data after updating SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, sql-update

imagine there are 2 tables :

```
T_Customer (p_customer_id, name, prename, country, age)
```

and

```
T_SomeInfo (f_customer_id, somebit, otherbit)
```

Now I want to update 1 random `somebit` and `OUTPUT` updated `T_Customer`, which belongs to `f_customer_id` of effected row.

Atm I've following statement :

```
UPDATE randombit SET randombit.somebit= 1
OUTPUT inserted.f_customer_id
FROM 
(
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM T_SomeInfo  
WHERE somebit= 0 AND otherbit = 0
ORDER BY NEWID()
) AS randombit
```

So I `f_customer_id` of my updated row.
But I'm not able to build a valid statement to OUTPUT a value from another table.
This is a statement I tried without success:

```
UPDATE randombit SET randombit.somebit= 1
OUTPUT customer.*
FROM T_Customer AS customer
WHERE customer.f_customer_id = inserted.f_customer_id
FROM 
(
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM T_SomeInfo  
WHERE somebit= 0 AND otherbit = 0
ORDER BY NEWID()
) AS randombit
```

Is there any solution to update and output (with `INNER JOIN` or `SELECT`) into one statement?

EDIT as example:
There are 2 customers :

```
T_Customer (1, "Smith", "John", "country", 10)
T_Customer (2, "John", "William", "country2", 20)
```

actually a update

```
UPDATE randombit SET randombit.somebit= 1
OUTPUT inserted.f_customer_id
FROM 
(
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM T_SomeInfo  
WHERE somebit= 0 AND otherbit = 0
ORDER BY NEWID()
) AS randombit
```

will output (if he's the random winner):

> 1

But I want to see

> 1, "Smith", "John", "country", 10

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: It's actually MS-SQL, but I eventually need this for SQLite later on too...

Comment: OUTPUT a value from another `Table` : I want to get information of recently updated `customer_id` at `T_SomeInfo`

Comment: You want (1) to update `randombit` table, (2) get updated `customer_id `s  and then (3) for these `customer_id`s you want to get information from `T_SomeInfo` table ?

Comment: @Bogdan Sahlean : yes, that's correct